# Twitter Bootstrap container max-width collapsing span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**UPDATED**
If I give a `max-width` to `.container` then my `spans` stops lining up properly.

```
<div class="container" style="max-width:940px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">1</div>
    <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">2</div>
    <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">3</div> 
    <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">4</div>  <!-- make a new line-->                
    <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">5</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems whatever I wrap my spans in it has the same effect. 
Is there any way to work around with this?

[LIVE PREVIEW HERE](http://33tpm.com/bs2/)

Comment: what is the width of your `spans` is more than `max-width`of `.container`?

Comment: provide a live demo or a jsFiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Bootstrap has a width of 12 columns.

Your 3 first div have 4 + 4 + 4 columns, so it breaks line before print others div.

Try to reduce width... By example with class "span2" and you'll see the change :)

Comment: I understand the logic of bootstrap. In this case the problem is not that though.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap operates a 12 column CSS grid system you have 5 * span4 in one row, a row can only contain 3 * span4 before it'll wrap to a new row.

If you want one solid row just remember the sum of spanX can't be > than 12

See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: I understand the logic of bootstrap. In this case the problem is not that though.